# WebApi2 - integrate auto generated authentication with other DBContext

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I'm using webapi2 Owin authentication and also have DBContext with the application db model

How can I integrate the users generated by the Owin authentication in the rest of the db model?

Answer (score 2):

In one of my migration projects we already had users table. So here is what I did to use that (instead of the default auto generated DB Context)

```
public class ApplicationOAuthProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
 ...
    public override Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var container = new MyUnityContainer();
        var _tokenService = container.GetContainer().Resolve<ITokenService>();
        var userId = _tokenService.Validate(context.UserName, context.Password);
        if (userId <= 0)
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
....
```

Here _tokenService is a wrapper on top of my custom DBContext and has a validate method like any other DB method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is nice, I did it once. But its not the case now.
What I need is to use the auto generated users DBContext with the rest of the model, not create my own authentication